# Create Circle button with network image and ripple effect

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a Widget that is a Circle button with Network image. When tapped there should be a ripple effect.

I have tried using Inkwell, but even when `type: MaterialType.circle` still the after the image is loaded it appears as Square image and it's not cropped to Circle.

```
return Material(
          elevation: 0,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Ink.image(
            image: NetworkImage(url),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 120.0,
            height: 120.0,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: null,
            ),
          ),
```

**EDIT**

Thanks guys! almost working with the following code:

**But how do I make the network image fade-in when loaded ?**

`FadeInImage.memoryNetwork` is not a ImageProvider it's a Widget how do i accomplish this ?

```
return Material(
            type: MaterialType.circle,
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            child: Ink.image(
              image: NetworkImage(url),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: null,
              ),
            ));
```

Comment: can you try `ClipRect` around your image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set to `Clip.hardEdge` the `clipBehavior` property in your `Material` widget .

```
Material(
      elevation: 0,
      type: MaterialType.circle,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      ...
```

Don't forget to Hot-restart the app.

More info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material/clipBehavior.html

**UPDATE**

Using `FadeInImage` widget

```
    Material(
              elevation: 0,
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              type: MaterialType.circle,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    placeholder: "resources/your_placeholder_image.png",
                    image:
                        'https://img.depor.com/files/ec_article_multimedia_gallery/uploads/2018/07/05/5b3e3ad01bd47.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 120.0,
                    height: 120.0,
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent, onTap: () {})),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I use ```FadeInImage.memoryNetwork``` in the child of an Ink.Image with this ?

Comment: Perfect!! Didn't think of nesting ```Material```.